# Вставка текущей даты в google spreadsheet

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Как можно сделать автоматическое заполнение текущей датой при изменении значения в одном из столбцов, НО чтобы это значение потом никогда не перезаполнялось?

Сейчас я сделал так:

```
=IF(A69<>"", TODAY(), "")
```

но при каждом применении сортировки дата перезаполняется на сегодняшнюю.

Comment: Формула не может менять значения других ячеек. Формула не может менять себя. По-моему, задача не решается.

Comment: Не очень понял:( ФОрмула вставляет значение в свою ячейку(где находится) по событию что другая ячейка А69 меняется. Проблема в том, что при изменении сортировки формула перезапускается и старые данные перезаполняются( Понимаете?

Comment: *Проблема в том, что* Прекрасно понимаю. *при изменении сортировки формула перезапускается и старые данные перезаполняются* Верно. Чтобы этого не происходило, требуется заменить формулу в ячейке на её значение. А вот этого - изменения себя с формулы на значение,- она сделать не может. Решение только одно - VBA-процедура, в терминах Excel - макрос.

Comment: А в google spreadsheet нет Макросов? Вроде бы я про какие-то скрипты слышал исполняемые в них.

Comment: Есть, но не на *VBA*. А в *Excel* дату можно зафиксировать с помощью итерационных вычислений.  Это так, для общей информации. Не советую, есть подводные камни, при неумелом использовании можно пропустить ненужные зацикливания. Вообще, инструмент предназнвчен для точных вычислений.

Answer (score 0):

Это возможно сделать только при помощи Google Apps Script:

```
function myFunction(e) {

  try {
    if (!e || !e.range) return;
    if (e.range.columnStart > 1) {
      var targetCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, e.range.rowEnd - e.range.rowStart + 1);

      /* if you want insert the date once uncomment the row below
       *
       **/
      // if(!targetCell.getValue())
      targetCell.setValue(new Date());

    }
  } catch (err) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast(err.message, 'Error!!1');
  }
}
```

Назначьте `myFunction` функцией триггера события `EDIT`.

Рабочий пример и описание https://gist.github.com/oshliaer/b179e819c0ee0f44c37bba7cfbfd4f54